# keep rows that have data in list of columns python

Tags: python, pandas

How can I select rows that contain data in a specific list of columns and drop the ones that have no data at all in those specific columns?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
VC_sub_selection = final[final['VC'].isin(['ACTIVE', 'SILENT']) & final['Status'].isin(['Test'])]

data_usage_months = list(data_usage_res.columns)
```

This is an example of the data set

```
item    VC     Status     Jun 2016   Jul 2016
1       Active Test       Nan        1.0
2       Silent Test       Nan        Nan
3       Active Test       2.0        3.0
4       Silent Test       5.0        Nan
```

What I would like to achieve is that item 1,3,4 will stay in the data set and that item 2 will be deleted. So the condition that applies is: if all months are `Nan` than drop row.

Thank you,

Jeroen

Comment: @Ukimiku I have edited my question, is it clear now?

Comment: What exactly is the selection criterion i.e. why is item 2 dropped? That at least one of the entries for `Jun 2016` and `Jul 2016` is not `Nan`?

Comment: if all months are Nan than drop row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Nickil's solution answers the question, it does not take into account that more date columns may be added later. Hence, using the index position of a column might not be sufficient in future situations.

The solution presented below does not use the index, rather it uses a regex to find the date columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# item    VC     Status     Jun 2016   Jul 2016
# 1       Active Test       Nan        1.0
# 2       Silent Test       Nan        Nan
# 3       Active Test       2.0        3.0
# 4       Silent Test       5.0        Nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'item': [1,2,3,4],
                   'VC': ['Active', 'Silent', 'Active', 'Silent'],
                   'Status': ['Test'] * 4,
                   'Jun 2016': [None, None, 2.0, 5.0],
                   'Jul 2016': [1.0, None, 3.0, None]})

regex_pattern = r'[a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{4}'

date_cols = list(filter(lambda x: re.search(regex_pattern, x), df.columns.tolist()))

df_res = df.dropna(subset=date_cols, how='all')

#     Jul 2016  Jun 2016 Status      VC  item
# 0       1.0       NaN   Test  Active     1
# 2       3.0       2.0   Test  Active     3
# 3       NaN       5.0   Test  Silent     4
```